# I have an error in my project when executing the command mvn verify -U

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build my project using maven, because I am using maven, as the title says, I am getting an error when I run the command mvn verify -U, in the terminal the following appears:

could not find artifact org.netbeans.api: org-netbeans-api-visual: jar: RELEASE731 in Central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

To make it a little clearer I am going to attach a print screen[a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvWSY.png)

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml? Probably the error is there.

Comment: The problem is the given artifact only exists in those versions: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.netbeans.api/org-netbeans-api-visual  and not in `RELEASE731`...

Comment: As the error rightly mentioned RELEASE731 is not present within https://repo1.maven.org/maven2. RELEASE731  artifact it located at Spring Plugins repository - https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/netbeans/api/org-netbeans-api-visual/RELEASE731/.